# Android (mobile) Keyboard Shortcuts Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, android

In Google Sheets on a PC it is possible to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> to insert the current time into a (time formatted) cell in Google Sheets.

How can this be done when using a sheet on an android mobile phone keyboard?

IN edit:
I see that =now() will insert the current time (acknowledgements to @OlegS) but the cell has conditional formatting according to the time of day (in 3 bands - am, pm and evening). Entering the time using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> applies the correct colour but =now() does not seem to respect the conditional format. The condition is:
(for example)

`value is between 10:00:00 and 16:00:00`

and the cell is given a different fill colour.

Is this because the full result of =now() includes the date as well as the time in a complete string and is there a way within the function to limit the result just to the time element?

Comment: This shortcut won't work on phone, instead you can use formula NOW() to return current time and paste it as value.

Comment: Yes, NOW() returns date as well, to get time value, wrap it in TIMEVALUE(NOW()).

Comment: @OlegS That works perfectly with the conditional formatting. Thanks. If you would add that as an answer I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts won't work on Android. Instead, you have to use the formula `=NOW()` which will provide the complete date and time result in a cell.

To get just the time value for conditional formatting use `TIMEVALUE(NOW())`